# Repairing damaged indoor teak furniture

Tags: staining, refinishing

I have a teak console that was damaged by friend who had it stored in their house.

This damage was caused by water rings.

[image]

And this was caused by melted wax from a candle!

[image]

I've scraped the wax off with a razor as best I could. I guess the next step is paper towels and an iron.

I thought that a light buffing with 000 steel wool followed by teak oil would be a good idea. But then I started second guessing myself.

Note: The piece is about 35 years old and I've been the only owner. It was oiled annually for the first half dozen years and has not been touched since. It is stored indoors.

Comment: This is an excellent illustration of how poor the protection provided by an oil finish can truly be (sorry). But, oil finishes are considered easily repairable so at least a partial fix *is* to simply apply more oil. Test on just one spot to see how this works, as it may not provide the seamless repair you are probably after.

Comment: Have you had a chance to do that test? Or did you go another route? Please don't make this another abandoned Q here -_-

Comment: Damn shame. That's very nice looking wood. I know in the past I have seen products offered at any of the regular woodworking companies that are made for removing water rings or it is at least listed as one of the treatment's many features. I always thought the (damp) paper towel and iron method was removing dents and / or for use on more traditional varnish or lacquer finishes. Oils can just be re-oiled (with a bit of pre-sanding if you like). I hesitate here but I have seen some folk remedies listed for this too. I cannot recommend them and have not used them myself. (cont.)

Comment: Some swear by coating the area in mayonnaise or other substances then removing and cleaning up afterwards. You can search that yourself if interested. One I heard of years ago, had to do with gently scrubbing with a toothpaste slurry. Maybe a layman's attempt instead of using pumice stone etc. to polish out the rings. Again, maybe over-kill for an oiled wood finish. One last thing, I have used and seen good results with Howard's Restore-a-Finish products for this problem. Link here. https://www.amazon.com/Howard-RF3016-Restor-Finish-16-Ounce/dp/B000C0182W/ref=psdc_15342871_t3_B01MSJID2T

Comment: thanks for all the advice. Living in New England means I started this project too late. Now I need a warm weekend day so I can open the windows to even just do the test!

Comment: and it is a nice piece. There are 4 vertical roll tops on the bottom!